# jquery: how to move <select> and keep the functionality

Tags: jquery

I have a div that contains a form with two select menus.

I cloned and moved the div containing the selects (not the entire form) using the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var cloned_language = $('#order__header').clone();
        var header_languages = $('.top_menu.main_menus');
        (header_languages).append(cloned_language);
      });
```

The problem is that the functionality of the select menus is now broken. This is the error I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of null .

Any ideas on how to fix it? How can I link the cloned selects with the original ones?
By 'link' I mean that I want that the original select to change when I click on the cloned one (same option to be selected).

LE: I've tried clone(true) but the event is not keep.

Comment: Please supply HTML code as well

Comment: _"How can I link the cloned selects with the original ones"_ - What do you mean by "link"? Are you actually using `.submit()` (as mentioned in the error) somewhere in your other code? As an aside, you don't need parentheses around `header_languages` in order to call `.append()`.

Comment: this means that the element doesnt exist.. try doing a `.length` check on the `header_languages`

Comment: Are you sure, you meant "#order__header", not "#order_header"?

Comment: The clone part & append is ok (even with the extra parentheses and the __).

Comment: If you are trying to retain events `-->` `.clone(true)`

Answer (score 0):

Let say that your original select has `id="original_Select"` and the new one has `id="cloned_Select"`

```
$(document).on("change","#cloned_Select",function(){
     $("#original_Select").val($(this).val())
})
$(document).on("change","#original_Select",function(){
         $("#cloned_Select").val($(this).val())
    })
```

So when one of the select changes, the other one will change too

Comment: I am still learning - how can I use this? can you be more specific?

Comment: you should post your code first, to see what functionality has your <select>

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that the functionality of the select menus is now broken. This is the error I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of null .

That sounds like you placed your cloned `select` elements *outside* of the `form` element their originals are in. And then in their change(?) handler you try to access the submit method of the form, but your clones have no reference to that form, because they are not in it.

So first of all you will have to fix that, refer to the specific form element in some other way inside the handler, f.e. `var form = $("#formid");`

And then secondly I suppose you want to have the current values of your cloned selects send with the form as well – which will not happen, since they’re outside of it. So you will have to “transfer” the selected values from your clones to the originals (by setting the appropriate `option` elements of the latter ones to `selected`) before submitting your form.

If I am correct in these assumptions ;-), and you need further help – then show us more of your actual JS code for handling the events on your select fields please.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just re-bind it? Assume this is your event:

```
$('#order__header').change(function (){
      //your code
});
```

Take that function out and name it:

```
function changeEvent(){
      //your code
}
```

Then change the event handler to this :

```
$('#order__header').change(changeEvent);
```

Then, after you clone, re-bind it.

```
 var cloned_language = $('#order__header').clone();
 cloned_language.on("change", changeEvent);
```

But more code is needed to make this assumption a solution.